Not able to navigate through protected Routes in react js
This is the protected route code:
const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/checkAuth", {
          credentials: "include",
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.message === "authenticated") {
          setIsAuthenticated(true);
        } else {
          setIsAuthenticated(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        console.error("Error checking authentication:", error);
      }
    };

    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  return isAuthenticated ? <Route {...props} /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;

This is the App.jsx code:
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            <Route path="/new" element={<Main />} />
            <Route path="/passshow" element={<PassShow />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

I am unable to go to "/new" or "/passhow". My backend is properly giving the message as "authenticated".
I guess there is some problem in my protected route code. So, Can someone please check the code and tell me what i am missing or doing wrong?
Any kind of suggestions will be very grateful.
